# SQLite3 gets ignored with no error when Python script is called from C++

Tags: python, c++, sqlite

I'm using Anaconda, I've installed sqlite3 using the environments.

When I run my script in the IDE, it creates and populates the DB no problem.

When I run the script from C++, it ignores the SQLite3 parts giving no errors and no database is created or populated. I know the script does run when called from C++ because other parts of it still function, but it just ignores the SQLite aspect.

C++ part:

```
string command = "C:\\Anaconda3\\python.exe C:\\CoSim2\\PYTHON\\python\\MainMaster.py " + std::to_string(minute);
```

Python part:

```
import math
import sys
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path


conn = sqlite3.connect('CoSimTest.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PowerSysInfo(time REAL, NumOfNodes INT, NumOfBuses INT, BusLocation TEXT, PhaseNumber INT, v1 REAL, a1 REAL, phase1 INT, v2 REAL, a2 REAL, phase2 INT, v3 REAL, a3 REAL, phase3 INT)')

create_table()
```

**What's going on? Why does running the script in the IDE work perfectly, but when C++ runs the .py it just ignores the SQLite parts with no error?**

Comment: I should add in debugger: sqlite3._version_  will give: *** AttributeError: module 'sqlite3' has no attribute '_version_'

Comment: What is the current directory?

Comment: In spyder?  cwd = os.getcwd(). My working path directory is C:\\CoSim2\\PYTHON\\python\\. Is that what you mean? In OMNeT++, where the C++ is run, the 'workspace' is C:\\CoSim2, so it should be all good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i thought i'd post the solution to my own question in case others have this problem. 
`conn = sqlite3.connect('CoSimTest.db')` needs a full path as the local directory changes when not running it from the ide.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell from what you've provided how you're actually launching the python script. You have a string that replicates what you'd enter in a command line (I assume that's what the `std::to_string(minute)` part is?), but depending on how you're actually executing the script, it may expect launch parameters to be input differently.

Check to make sure your arguments are actually being seen by the python script.

Make sure your working directory is the same as what's used by your IDE.

Comment: The argument is simply passing time in the programme (OMNeT++ 4.3). This is then used later on in the python script for simulating other things and populating the database. But for example, even if i run script in the IDE leaving the requiredtime = float(sys.argv[1]) later on, it will still create the DB before giving an error that there is no inputted argument. So I don't think this is anything to do with the argument?

Comment: To be clearer, the arguments are being seen, as I am recording them in txt file. This is how I know the script works and is being called, but the SQLITE aspects are being simply ignored. It won't even create the DB like it would with runscript in the IDE

Comment: Are you using the same working directory as your IDE uses?

Comment: What do you mean by this? Maybe you are onto something. The working directory of the C++ is in a separate folder to anaconda. If you look at the C++ line you will see what i mean.

Comment: So i did  cwd = os.getcwd(). My working path directory is C:\\CoSim2\\PYTHON\\python\\. I feel the problem lies with something to do with the SQLite library, but i don't know anything about it?